# On ubuntu sever nginx not able to serve cross-domain image url

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have developed project using Django framework and getting image files from http://data.myothersite.org/data/images/agents/A_1747.jpg

In localhost I have tested and able to get all images in my listing page but on live server which has domain `http://www.myfirstsite.org` & I am not able to get all images which are hosted on `http://data.myothersite.org` and getting permission denied error.

I have tried to set `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin` http://data.myothersite.org/` in nginx conf file but not have any luck.

I have tried to find solution online also but not able to find.

Thanks.

Comment: Images by themselves (i.e. `<img>` tags) aren't subject to ACAO; how are you retrivieving and what's your code?

Comment: Are you able to view the images directly in your browser? Does the access denied come from data.myothersite.org? Maybe its simply file system permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to load images on `http://www.myfirstsite.org` from `http://data.myothersite.org` , you have to provide permissions in nginx conf of `http://data.myothersite.org` rather than in nginx conf of `http://www.myfirstsite.org`

Provide this header in nginx conf of `http://data.myothersite.org`

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://www.myfirstsite.org' always;
```

Reference: https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html